# Java Swing : drawLine very slow

Tags: java, swing, graphics, fullscreen, doublebuffered

I am writing a java application using swing in which I need to draw a grid above a square. In order to do so, I am using the `drawLine(...)` method provided by the `Graphics` class.

Everything works fine except that it takes a lot of time to draw each line (more than 20 sec for 50 lines...). I can even see the lines being drawn in real time. One weird thing is that the horizontal lines are drawn way faster than the vertical lines (almost instantly).

I might be doing something wrong. Here is the code for the grid.

```
public void drawGrid(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 20));
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = (int) (width * Utils.PLATE_RATIO);
    int step = pixelSize*gridSpacing;
    Color bright = new Color(255, 255, 255, 100);
    Color transparent = new Color(255, 255, 255, 20);
    for(int ix = insets.left + step;                        
            ix < width; ix += step){
        if(((ix - insets.left) / step) % 10 == 0){
            g.setColor(bright);
        }
        else{
            g.setColor(transparent);
        }
        g.drawLine(ix, insets.top, ix, height+insets.top);
    }
    for(int iy = insets.top+step;
            iy < (insets.top + height); iy += step){
        if(((iy - insets.top) / step) % 10 == 0){
            g.setColor(bright);
        }
        else{
            g.setColor(transparent);
        }
        g.drawLine(insets.left, iy, width + insets.left, iy);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is because you are not using double buffering. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html

Comment: Of course, how can I be so stupid. Thank you !

Comment: @SureshKumar swing components are double-buffering by default ...

Comment: @SureshKumar agreed with kleopatra - you cannot say if he is using double-buffered painting strategy or not by just this part of code. And the presented code is totally fine.

Comment: Single buffering would never take that long.

Comment: @MikleGarin and kleopatra : they are supposed to be double-buffered by default, but even setting the double-buffering manually to true didn't change the result. Is it possible that manual drawing is not double-buffered?
JarrodSmith : as for the time, maybe the fact that I am working on an old netbook running on linux explains that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have posted is fine, there is no problems in it.
Here is a working example of a component using your method (a bit simplified):

```
public static class MyGrid extends JComponent
{
    private int step = 10;

    public MyGrid ()
    {
        super ();
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize ()
    {
        return new Dimension ( 500, 500 );
    }

    protected void paintComponent ( Graphics g )
    {
        super.paintComponent ( g );
        drawGrid ( g );
    }

    public void drawGrid ( Graphics g )
    {
        int width = getWidth ();
        int height = getHeight ();
        Color bright = new Color ( 255, 255, 255, 200 );
        Color transparent = new Color ( 255, 255, 255, 100 );

        for ( int ix = step; ix < width; ix += step )
        {
            if ( ( ix / step ) % 10 == 0 )
            {
                g.setColor ( bright );
            }
            else
            {
                g.setColor ( transparent );
            }
            g.drawLine ( ix, 0, ix, height );
        }

        for ( int iy = step; iy < height; iy += step )
        {
            if ( ( iy / step ) % 10 == 0 )
            {
                g.setColor ( bright );
            }
            else
            {
                g.setColor ( transparent );
            }
            g.drawLine ( 0, iy, width, iy );
        }
    }
}
```

I guess there is some problem outside that piece of code.

P.S. A bit an offtopic but...

I suggest you to calculate the visible part of the painting area (using either JComponent's `getVisibleRect ()` method or Graphics `g.getClip ().getBounds ()` method) and limit your paintings with only that area.

That small optimization could speedup component's painting in times if it is really large (for example with 10000x10000 pixels component's area).

Comment: I don't think there was any problem outside that code, I did more or less the same as you. I now replaced `getWidth()` by `getVisibleRect().getSize()`. See my solution below.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I solved the problem using Double-Buffering, as advised by @sureshKumar. I am simply drawing on an offscreen image and simply calling `drawImage()` when the drawing is over. This seems to do the trick.

**Edit:** this seems to be useful only if you want to call your painting methods (in my case `drawGrid()`) from outside of the `paintComponent(...)` method.

Here is the code:

```
private Graphics bufferGraphics;
private Image offScreen;
private Dimension dim;
//other attributes not shown...

public CentralPanel(){
    //Some initialization... (not shown)

    //I added this listener so that the size of my rectangle
    //and of my grid changes with the frame size
    this.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            dim = getVisibleRect().getSize();
            offScreen = createImage(dim.width, dim.height);
            bufferGraphics = offScreen.getGraphics();
            repaint();
            revalidate();
        }
        //other methods of ComponentListener not shown
    });
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(offScreen, 0, 0, null);
}

public void drawGrid(){
    int width = dim.width - insets.left - insets.right;
    width -= (width % plateSize.getXSize());
    int height = (int) (width*Utils.PLATE_RATIO);
    height -= (height % plateSize.getYSize());
    int step = pixelSize*gridSpacing;
    Color bright = new Color(255, 255, 255, 100);
    Color transparent = new Color(255, 255, 255, 20);
    for(int ix = insets.left + step;                        
            ix < (width+insets.left); ix += step){
        if(((ix - insets.left) / step) % 10 == 0){
            bufferGraphics.setColor(bright);
        }
        else{
            bufferGraphics.setColor(transparent);
        }
        //I am now drawing on bufferGraphics instead 
        //of the component Graphics
        bufferGraphics.drawLine(ix, insets.top, ix, height+insets.top);
    }
    step *= Utils.PLATE_RATIO;
    for(int iy = insets.top+step;
            iy < (insets.top + height); iy += step){
        if(((iy - insets.top) / step) % 10 == 0){
            bufferGraphics.setColor(bright);
        }
        else{
            bufferGraphics.setColor(transparent);
        }
        bufferGraphics.drawLine(insets.left, iy, width + insets.left, iy);
    }
}
```

P.S.: If this should be added as an edit to my question, please tell me and I'll do it.

Comment: Jesus, why wouldn't you just extend a JComponent which already has a double-buffering strategy (actually every Swing component has it and uses it by default)? That will save a lot of your time and you won't need to invent a wheel... All you need to do when you extend a JComponent is to extend paintComponent method and... yes, paint! Thats all. No need to even bother about the double-buffering.

Comment: One more thing - you didn't get what i was talking about when i mentioned using `getVisibleRect ()` method to avoid meaningless painting. I was talking about excluding the lines (and those parts of lines) which are NOT visible on the component. For example if your component is contained inside an active scroll - you will only see a part of it at a time. You should avoid painting outside that visible part when it is possible. In your case you could easily exclude the lines which aren't visible.

Comment: @MikleGarin I understood what was the issue now. I was actually calling `drawGrid(Graphics g)` from another function, but I believe only the `painComponent(Graphics g)` is automatically double-duffered, and not everything painted with the JComponent's Graphics. Anyway, it makes it way easier if I can call the `drawGrid(...)` method from outside `paintComponent(...)`, so I will keep my implementation. Thanks for the comment on the `getVisibleRect()`, I got you point now.